# How to change button content to next alphabet when i click, like a to b in android

Tags: android, button

I have 3 buttons, button 1 content is 'a' , button2 is b, button 3 is c and so on. Now when I click button 1 it should be changed as b(next alphabet), button 2 is c, button 3 is d. Similarly if I click button 2, then button 2 should be c, button 3 is d , button 1 is b and so on.

My Code :

```
Button but1, but2,but3; 
String c; 
but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{ 
    @Override public void onClick(View v) 
    { 
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub String buttonText = (String)
         but1.getText(); 
         c=buttonText; 
         char c = 'a'; 
         c = (char) (((c -'a' + 1) % 26) + 'a'); 
         but1.setText(c.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you try so far and we will give you advise

Comment: At first try it : Simply use ASCII Number, on click add + 1  to this number if his value is not  z (122), if z go back to a(97), then convert ASCII number to string and simply change the text of the button for the new letter. [ASCII TABLE](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

Comment: The situation is anything but clear to me...

You say you have three seperate buttons, yet if you click on any button all button's letters will be changed to the next one in the alphabet?

Also, please tell us which ideas/theories to approach this issue you've already came up with yourself... With this I probably would've been more able to understand what it is you try to do here...

Comment: Button but1, but2,but3;
 String c;
 
            but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    String buttonText = (String) but1.getText();
    c=buttonText;
    char c = 'a';
    c = (char) (((c -'a' + 1) % 26) + 'a');
    but1.setText(c.getText().toString());

Comment: I could not able to get the changed content to the button

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right

```
(char)('a'+(c + 1 - 'a')%26)
```

its correct, i dont understand the question then. If you want to spread this to other buttons you should add into onClickListener same text for other buttons, and moreover you should set this onClickListener to other buttons.

Comment: In that code, last line                                                                   but1.setText(c.getText().toString());                                            i am getting error :cannot invoke gettext to primitive type char

Comment: how I can set c value to button ?